# SVN, SSL certificate negotiation failed. However we don't use SSL certificate on our SVN Server

Tags: ssl, tortoise-svn, ssl-certificate, rubygems

Can you tell me please, at my workplace we don’t use SSL certificates for SVN, however while running RUby on Rails command that checks SVN ( = Churn) still expects it and gives back the  following error:

> SSL negotiation failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856
>   (https://137.172.75.98)

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the protocol from https: to http: in the RoR command? That might fix it.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply however, this solution doesn't work as SVN replies: 'http://137.172.75.98' path not found

Comment: @DanielMyasnikov - from server-side pure http must be  supported also, but it seems you have ssl-only host. Enable http or add server-cert